# Data is not shared between few sessions within the same session factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a question - how can I make hibernate know throughout different sessions within the same `SessionFactory` of what is going on in another session?

Example:

- in first session I delete/add something (it is not persisted yet, it is "in batch"
- I call an event which creates a new session and I'd expect it to know that some delete/add operations are in batch, and it should include them in the query that I call

The problem I face now is that the event doesn't know that some entites are about to be removed when the first session is flushed, and it includes them in the query if I fetch them.

I use 2nd level cache and I thought this should help, but it doesn't.

Comment: You are looking for Transaction Isolation Levels. I'm not sure how that works with Hibernate, but you now have something to google for.

Comment: @Jorn: if you are suggesting having hibernate use uncommitted reads, that seems like a scary solution. Also not what the OP is asking for, they want work that isn't even persisted, just stuff changed in session. Is that what is meant by "in batch"? This sounds like an unreasonable expectation to me, maybe commit your work in chunks so other sessions can legitimately see it.

Comment: by "in batch" I meant that first session has a queue of five operations (inserts, deletes) and I'd expect that the second session "knows" about that, so it includes those in the queries that it is making.
E.g. now if I delete something in first session and in second session I try to fetch it, it is fetched instead of returning null.

Comment: I agree with @NathanHughes that using uncommitted reads is probably a bad idea. Perhaps you can commit each batch separately? That'd make the changes visible to other transactions. But then you can't roll back any more, obviously.